# По барабану

Tags: фразеология

По барабану: безразлично, всё равно.

Знатоки, можете объяснить, при чём тут барабан? "По барабану" можно ударить, но каким образом это связано с чувством безразличия, ума не приложу!

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считается, что это арготический эмотивный фразеологизм, выражающий  спокойствие: всё по барабану, также: держать стойку.

По одной версии, редуцировано из «что горох по барабану» - равнодушен, как барабан, когда по нему стучат. По другой — эфвемизм к по фигу (или его матерному аналогу).

Есть ещё версия: определённый ритм барабана используется для вхождения в трансовое состояние, каковое раньше называли одержимостью. В этом состоянии человек становится не восприимчив ко многим вещам.

И еще интересный вариант: всё делать незаинтересованно,по указанию, по необходимости.
http://www.frazeologiya.ru/fraza/baraban.htm
Под барабан, по барабану (вставать, ложиться, ходить и т.п.) — под звуки, при звуках такого инструмента. — Балчуговский завод походил на военный лагерь, где вставали и ложились по барабану, обедали и шабашили по барабану и даже в церковь ХОДИЛИ ПО БАРАБАНУ. Мамин-Сибиряк. — Однако это не Петербург, где ложишься под барабан и встаешь под барабан. Никулин.

Answer (score 3):

Эвфемизм от матерного выражения с тем же смысловым значением. Барабан у военного барабанщика висел на уровне чуть ниже пояса отсюда и метонимия (перенос).

Answer (score 1):

Считается, что чувства, зарождаются в сердце. Именно в области груди находится энергетический отдел, отвечающий за духовную жизнь человека, поэтому говорят: "Это мне по сердцу, это мне по душе", - в том случае, когда испытывают положительные эмоции. При отрицательных же, говорят: "Не по душе мне это, не по сердцу". А барабаном или бубном называют голову: "Сейчас по барабану получишь!... В бубен как дам тебе!"  Голова - это безчувственный процессор, руководящий материальным аспектом жизнедеятельности человека. Поэтому, если что-то безразлично, не трогает струны души, оно доходит лишь до головы, т.е до барабана, и становится "по барабану".